When a fully faithful functor from an abelian category to itself will be an equivalence
Let $A$ be an abelian category. Suppose $i:A\to A$ is a fully faithful functor from $A$ to itself. I wonder when the functor will be an equivalence.
If $A$ is a "nice" category, I think $i$ will be an equivalence. For example, if $A$ is the category of $k$-vector spaces, then due to dimension, $i$ will be an equivalence.
In general, I think this may be not correct. Maybe there exists some counterexamples. I wonder what kinds of general conditions we can put for $A$ and $i$ such that $i$ will be an equivalence.
I am interested in the case $A=\mathrm{Coh}(X)$ is the category of coherent sheave on a smooth projective variety $X$ over $\mathbb{C}$. But I also wonder for more general siutation.

An easy counterexample (for the general question) is if $\mathscr A$ is the category of finite-dimensional $\mathbf Z$-graded vector spaces (equivalently, $\mathbf G_m$-representations, or coherent sheaves on $B\mathbf G_m$). For a self-map $\phi \colon \mathbf Z \to \mathbf Z$ with finite fibres, you get a functor $\mathscr A \to \mathscr A$ by $\bigoplus_{i \in \mathbf Z} A_i \mapsto \bigoplus_{i \in \mathbf Z} \bigoplus_{j \in \phi^{-1}(i)} A_j$. This is fully faithful if and only if $\phi$ is injective, and essentially surjective if and only if $\phi$ is surjective.

Thanks! This is a great counterexample. From this example,  it seems we should put some finiteness condition on the abelian category $A$ such that $i$ can be an equivalence.

The property you are asking for reminds me of the Rank-Nullity Theorem in linear algebra. A direct corollary is that a linear map from a finite dimensional vector space to itself is bijective iff it is injective. The example you give, namely vector spaces, is "higher" linear algebraic, in that the category of vector spaces is semisimple. Indeed, $A$ being finite semisimple and $i$ being linear is a sufficient condition for fully faithful (i.e., "injective") to be equivalent to being an equivalence. (continued below)

Indeed, a linear functor between semisimple categories is fully faithful if and only if distinct simples are mapped to distinct simples. So if $A$ only has finitely many isomorphism classes of simples, the result again follows by counting.
